# counts of unique data from a data frame

Tags: r, unique

Ok, so lets take some simple data

```
A <- c(1997,2000,2000,1998,2000,1997,1997,1997)
B <- c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0)
df <- data.frame(A,B)
```

Now if we run the following

```
length(df$B[df$A==1997& df$B==0])
length(df$B[df$A==1997& df$B==1])
```

We get the counts of each unique A and B combinations.

But I want to output a results that will search for each `unique` A value (representing a year) and output the sum of B (being binary). The results can be a data.frame or matrix. Any suggestions on how to tackle such a problem?

The results could look like:
[image]

Comment: Just `table(df)`, man. Or `with(df, table(B, A))` or exact output. Or `library(reshape2) ; dcast(df, B ~ A, length, value.var = "B")`.

Comment: Following what @DavidArenburg suggested you can simply do `t(table(df))` which will give you the requested table.

Comment: @Konrad don't think transposing a whole data set just in order to save keystrokes is a good practice.